# Setting The Members of a C Struct

Tags: c

```
some_struct = some_function;  //some_function returns a pointer to an instance of a struct
some_struct->num = 8; //num is an int
```

The second line creates a segmentation fault, when I try to use gdb with the `p some_struct->num command`, it says `Cannot access memory at address 0x0`

How do I set the value of some_struct->num without creating a segmentation fault?

Comment: how does `some_function` look like exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function is returning a NULL pointer. Make sure it returns valid memory for a `some_struct` type.